# Flutter Android project with Agora SDK: 'error: cannot find symbol'

Tags: android, flutter, import, package, agora.io

I'm working on a Flutter project where I have to implement some part of the apps functionality on the native side. After successfully integrating a screen sharing feature through the Agora SDK on the iOS side I'm now working on the Android part. Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine;
                   ^
symbol:   class RtcEngine
location: package io.agora.rtc
```

I'm following this tutorial by Agora: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/screensharing_android?platform=Android#use-multi-processing-to-send-video-streams-from-screen-sharing-and-local-camera

Apparently the specific symbol of `RtcEngine` from the Agora RTC package is not found while importing, even though the package itself is known to the compiler (changing the package name to a non-existent package name leads to a different error, which says that the package is not known). Since this is not the issue I'm wondering why this one symbol from it should not be known.

Has anyone of you had this or a similar issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution to my problem. The reason for the app not building due to the unknown symbols from the `io.agora.rtc` package was that  the actual package was indeed not added as a dependency to the gradle files (`build.gradle`) within the project. The reason why the package path of `io.agora.rtc` was known to the compiler despite of this, was that the path `io/agora/rtc` existed within the project. Since symbols like `RtcEngine` weren't within this and not imported through any different way the compiler threw this error. Importing the package through the gradle files therefore added the missing symbols and made the app build again.

Hope this knowledge helps you! Have a great day.